# Tricky issue passing data from form to form in django

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am a django newbie and have one more big struggle for longer time... :/

User can choose a 'main language' which is set as ForeignKey. User can choose 'further languages' as ManyToMany (Checkbox). Assuming, user selects english as 'main' language, so english has to be filterd out from the 'further languages'... have been searching so much and have no idea how to do it. Is this even possible without JavaScript?

Of course, I could set the 'queryset' in the second form but it would filter the objects after the submit... The similar problem is, when a selected country has to be connected to the proper zipcodes...

I am very thankful for any hints. 
Best regards.

```
class Country(models.Model):

    enter code here
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Länder'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country


class ZipCode(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Postleitzahlen'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.zipcode, self.city)


class MainLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(verbose_name='Hauptsprache', max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Hauptsprachen'
        ordering = ['language']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language


class SecondLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(verbose_name='weitere Sprachen', max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'weitere Sprachen'
        ordering = ['language']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language


class CustomUserprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Vorname', max_length=40,
                            null=True, blank=True)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name='Land',
                                null=True, blank=True)

    zipcode = models.ForeignKey(ZipCode, blank=True, null=True)

    main_language = models.ForeignKey(
        MainLanguage, verbose_name='Hauptsprache',
        null=True, blank=True)

    second_language = models.ManyToManyField(
        SecondLanguage, verbose_name='weitere Sprachen',
        null=True, blank=True)


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    second_language = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=SecondLanguage.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

        class Meta:
            model = CustomUserprofile
            exclude = ('user',)
```

Comment: it is not an issue - it is only js task, except one case - if FK field already specified, so you can `exclude` it from queryset of second form

Comment: Isn't there some kind of 'best practice' for django? I mean, it is a quiet common task or not? Have no much knowledge about JavaScript at the moment.... :/